# Constraint Optimization with constrOptim

Tags: r

I have a production function which want to maximize:

```
production_function <- function(L, K) {
  ;K*L+L
}
```

And there is a constraint function which is related to the total cost of production

```
constraint_function <- function(L,K) {
  2 * L + 1.4 * K 
}
```

In this case I want total cost is equal to 100 while maximizing production

So I created:

```
result<-constrOptim(theta = c(30,30), ui = rbind(c(2,1.4),c(0,1),c(1,0)), ci = c(100,0,0), f=production_function, grad = NULL)
```

Where L>0, K>0 and   2 * L + 1.4 * K >100

First of all It responds as Error in f(theta, ...) : argument "K" is missing, with no default, how can I solve this problem?

And secondly, how can I impose  2 * L + 1.4 * K = 100 rather than   2 * L + 1.4 * K > 100 as in the case?

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are not correct. You need to define them with one parameter and not 2:

```
production_function <- function(theta) {
  theta[2]*theta[1]+theta[1]
}

constraint_function <- function(theta) {
  2 * theta[1] + 1.4 * theta[2]
}




result<-constrOptim(c(30,30),production_function, NULL, rbind(c(2,1.4),c(0,1),c(1,0)), c(100,0,0))
```

Also notice that the constraints are represented such that `ui %*% theta - ci >= 0` So equality and greater than 0 are similar